# Trouble understanding a for loop in Swift 3

Tags: for-loop, swift3

I am studying some code to try to learn Swift 3. I came across this for loop and can't decipher what exactly it is doing. If you understand it, could you try to break it down with an explanation?

```
var size = 0
var candidate = (value: 0, index: 0)
for i in 0..<count {
    if size == 0 {
        candidate = (A[i], i)
        size += 1
    } else {
        if candidate.value != A[i] {
            size -= 1
        } else {
            size += 1
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// set variable "size" to the value of zero

var size = 0

    // set variable "candidate" to be a NAMED TUPLE with initial values (0,0)

    var candidate = (value: 0, index: 0)

    // start a FOR loop from 0 to "count" which by the way has not been defined yet, so that might be a problem.

    for i in 0..<count {

        // if size is zero, then we set candidate equal to ARRAY "A" of index "i" and increment 'size'... and by the way, this Array "A" has not been defined anywhere, so that might be a problem.
        if size == 0 {
            candidate = (A[i], i)
            size += 1

        // otherwise, we do one of two things: 1) if the 'candidate' tuple's (value:) parameter is NOT equal to the value of Array 'A''s index of 'i', then we decrement 'size' ... by the way this Array 'A' has not yet been defined so that might be a problem... or 2) increment the value of 'size.' 

        } else {
            if candidate.value != A[i] {
                size -= 1
            } else {
                size += 1
            }
        }
    }
```

So it looks like there should be an array somewhere called 'A'

and 'count' should really be A.count

Basically the loop is (seems to be trying to) going through the Array 'A' and comparing adjacent values and adjusting the 'size' variable as a result of each of these comparisons.

Comment: The array is declared in code not posted. count is a variable set to equal A.count. Thanks for your insight.